# how to resolve org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException

Tags: java, spring, hsqldb

I am using hsqldb standalone as my database. i have a `hsqldb.jar(hsqldb-2.0.0)` which i added on my project build path so my project will find out where is my `hsqldb.jar`. i am using spring with these. my spring bean is:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="sqlMapClient"
        class="org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean">

        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref local="adapterDataSource" />
        </property>


        <property name="configLocation"
            value="classpath:/com/hsqldb/example/dao/ibatis/SqlMapConfig.xml" />


    </bean>

    <bean id="adapterDataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="data/db/hsqldb.jar" />
        <property name="username" value="SA" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="testingDao" class="com.hsqldb.example.dao.TestingDao"
        init-method="setTestDao" depends-on="moodleAuthenticationDetails">
        <property name="sqlMapClient">
            <ref local="sqlMapClient" />
        </property>

    </bean>
    <bean id="moodleAuthenticationDetails"
        class="com.hsqldb.example.HsqlDBAuthentication"></bean>
</beans>
```

and i have a method which will return me a data source which is as below :

```
public static DataSource getDataSource(String filePath){
        String url;
        //url="jdbc:hsqldb:file:"+filePath;
        url = "jdbc:hsqldb:file:D:/EclipseWorskpace/ew-pg/lmexadapter/hsqldb-example/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/data/db/hsqldb.jar";
        BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        basicDataSource.setUsername("SA");
        basicDataSource.setPassword("password");
        basicDataSource.setDriverClassName("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver");
//      basicDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://IP/moodle");
        basicDataSource.setUrl(url);
        System.out.println("$$$$$$$$ URL is : " + url);
        return basicDataSource;
    }
```

but while running my test case by junit test it's giving me an exception :

```
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver' for connect URL 'data/db/hsqldb.jar'
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1273)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1192)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:884)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:113)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:213)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:264)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1266)
    ... 39 more
```

please help to resolve this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BasicDataSource` `url` property in your Spring config should not be the path to your jar.  See some examples of working Spring configs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380882/how-to-embed-hsqldb-in-file-with-spring-to-a-webapp).

(The `DataSource` class you've written won't do anything unless you make Spring aware of it.  But you don't have to write such a class -- just fix the `url` property in your config.)