# HSQLDB embedded in Spring MVC application with file-based persistence

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, hsqldb, in-memory-database, embedded-database

I am working with a Spring MVC web application that simulates an in-memory persistence layer using a combination of Maps, Lists, etc. Obviously, a database is much more performant, so I want to use HSQLDB. I want the database to be embedded from the standpoint of being accessible only via the application and starting/stopping with the web application. But I want the data to be permanent, i.e. file-based so even if the application is restarted, the data is loaded from a file. Is there a way to achieve this?

**Note** *(added 4/28/2015)*: I want this to work in the following way:

1. Web application starts up
2. Web application checks presence of database (file) in configured location
3. If database is not available at configured location, it creates by running a provided SQL initialization script.

I added the following to my Spring configuration file:

```
<bean id="embeddedDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:/usr/local/data/hsqldb/testdb" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
```

But I don't see any database file created at the location `/usr/local/data/hsqldb/`

Comment: It is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380882/how-to-embed-hsqldb-in-file-with-spring-to-a-webapp Note: My reputation does not allow me to add a comment, so posted in answer section.

Comment: Just create a `DataSource` bean with the appropriate properties. For file based HSQLDB, take a look at HSQL documentation: you only need to change the URL of the DB to make it file-persistent.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet I added a `datasource` configuration to my Spring configuration file but I did not see any database file created at the given location. Please review the note I added in my question. Thanks.